# django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf suggest url gives 404 error

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I am using django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf and have document configured with suggest completionfield. Also my viewset definitation has suggesters.

Document:

```
class ProductsDocument(Document):
    productName = fields.TextField(
        attr='productName',
        fields={
            'raw': fields.KeywordField(),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
        }
    )

    description = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.KeywordField(),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
            'lower': fields.Text(analyzer=html_strip),
        }
    )
```

Viewset:

```
class ProductsView(BaseDocumentViewSet):
    document = ProductsDocument
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    lookup_field = 'id'
    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        SuggesterFilterBackend,
        IdsFilterBackend,
        OrderingFilterBackend,
        DefaultOrderingFilterBackend,
        CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
        NestedFilteringFilterBackend,
        CompoundSearchFilterBackend,

    ]

    search_fields = (
        'productName',
        'price',
        'inStock',
        'description',
        'sellerprof.country.name',
    )

suggester_fields = {
        'productName_suggest': {
            'field': 'productName.suggest',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
            'default_suggester': SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
        },

        'description_suggest': {
            'field': 'description.suggest',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
            'default_suggester': SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
        },
        'productName_suggest': 'productName.suggest',
        'description_suggest': 'description.suggest',
    }
```

When I try using suggest completion URL, I got NotFoundError

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duxjd.png)

I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue. Someone provide me solution for that and it worked. So check my question from the below link if you have the same issue. Then the solution will work for you as well.

[Django elasticsearch DSL DRF suggetions issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769076/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf-suggetions-issue?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

You only need to inherit DocumentViewSet instead of BaseDocumentViewSet.

Comment: Thank you. I resumed my work on suggest. Followed answer from your post and it worked like a charm.